# Calculate translate on custom zoom in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement some custom zoom levels in d3 js. The zooming part is easy beacuse I can set the scale with zoom.scale.

But when I use the mouse wheel the svg jumps because I don't have the correct translations.
So does anybody know how to get the translate value from the scale and mouse position?

Comment: maybe you should share your code?